# Would time speed up on an object you're moving towards?

Tags: visible-light, photons, time, space

When we look at stars, we see light that is years old. This would mean that if aliens were to look at earth, they would see how the earth looked in the past.

My question is, if you were to move closer to an object so that you receive more photons in your eyes, would it look like the time sped up on the object? And the same if you were to move away from an object, would the time move slower?

Just a question that popped up in my head, thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106124/would-approaching-a-distant-star-at-near-the-speed-of-light-unfold-its-entire-hi is a duplicate. Keep in mind that the relativistic effect called "time dilation" is independent of signal retardation: it tells you about the time over there even though you won't see the light from that even for a while yet. This kind of question forces you to deal with both issues at once.